# How to set the initial message for SWT Combo

Tags: swt

SWT Text has a method called `setMessage` which can be used with `SWT.SEARCH` to put an initial faded-out message in the text box.

Can something similar be done with SWT Combo? It seems it does not have the `setMessage()` method, so it seems like some other trick needs to be applied here.

Comment: BWT, `setMessage` It is typically used with `SWT.SEARCH`, but works for all Text widgets with `SWT.SINGLE` style.

Comment: Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it. "[ask]" and its linked pages will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the Combo does not have regular API to set a message like the text widget does.

You could try to use a `PaintListener` to draw the message text while the Combo text is empty.

```java
combo.addPaintListener( new PaintListener() {
  @Override
  public void paintControl( PaintEvent event ) {
    if( combo.getText().isEmpty() ) {
      int x = ...; // indent some pixels
      int y = ...; // center vertically
      event.gc.drawText( "enter something", x, y );
    }
  }
} );
```

In addition, you would need several listeners that redraw the Combo after its *native* appearance was updated.

```java
combo.addListener( SWT.Modify, event -> combo.redraw() );
```

A modify listener is certainly required to show/hide the message but there are probably more listeners necessary to redraw the message when it is invalidated. This answer may give further hints which events are necessary to capture: [How to display a hint message in an SWT StyledText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073463/how-to-display-a-hint-message-in-an-swt-styledtext/)

Note, however, that drawing onto controls other than Canvas is unsupported and may not work on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler alternative to the paint listener that worked for my purposes involves programatically setting the text and text color using a `FocusListener`. Here is an example:

```
    final String placeholder = "Placeholder";
    combo.setForeground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
    combo.setText(placeholder);
    combo.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            String text = combo.getText();
            if(text.isEmpty()) {
                combo.setText(placeholder);
                combo.setForeground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            String text = combo.getText();
            if(text.equals(placeholder)) {
                combo.setText("");
                combo.setForeground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is actually pretty interesting. I may give it a try when I am around a combo again.