# Hint on multiline SWT Text

Tags: java, swt

I am experiencing what might be a potential bug in SWT.

The hint of a [`Text`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html) widget seems to become invisible for multiline texts (`SWT.MULTI` option).

```
 Text multilineText = new Text(parent, SWT.MULTI);
 multilineText.setMessage("[undisplayed hint <:( ]");
```

Is there something that I am missing?

NOTE: I am applying a `GridDataFactory.fillDefaults()` layout to the widget.

Comment: On which operating system/window system do you see this?

Comment: Not sure if this counts as an answer or not, but I just found that the message text will display if I set the SWT.SEARCH style in addition to SWT.MULTI.
The only drawback is that it will also display a magnifying glass to the left of the text field.
(I tested this on Windows 10 21H2.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Text` with `SWT.MULTI` does not support `setMessage`.

There is an open bug report [328832](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328832) for this, but it has been open since 2011.

Looking at the macOS version of the `setMessage` code it explicitly checks for `SWT.SINGLE`.

Comment: I use the workaround described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073463/how-to-display-a-hint-message-in-an-swt-styledtext to show a hint message in a `StyledText`. Maybe you can adapt the code fo multiline text widgets.